# odd JFET configuration

Tags: jfet

I was looking at figure 33 of the [OP77 datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/OP77.pdf), and the JFET labeled D2 has an odd connection. Based on the way the circuit works that JFET must be a diode right? So why is the JFET connected as it is in the figure?

Comment: I thought this was a duplicate (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16966/transistor-as-low-leakage-diode/) But now I see that question asked about the BJT, while your question asks about the JFET.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JFET is acting as a diode. So why not just use a diode? The main reason for using a JFET as a diode is that it has low leakage compared to ordinary diodes.

Comment: any recommendations on a SMD or through hole JFET that would work?

Answer (score 2):

It is acting like a diode. Because the circuit in question is an absolute value amplifier it has to handle positive signal excursions differently to how it handles negative signals because basically it's a precision full-wave rectifier.